# Error running unit test for Jersey + GAE service

Tags: google-app-engine, junit, jersey

I have implemented some Restful service and use Google App Engine for database part.
Every thing works fine, I have tested it using cURL. The problem is I need to create 
a set of unit tests for similar services.

Here is error I get:

```
    Jan 23, 2012 10:10:42 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Jan 23, 2012 10:10:42 AM com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory$InMemoryTestContainer <init>
INFO: Creating low level InMemory test container configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/
Jan 23, 2012 10:10:42 AM com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory$InMemoryTestContainer start
INFO: Starting low level InMemory test container
Jan 23, 2012 10:10:42 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.11 12/09/2011 10:27 AM'
Jan 23, 2012 10:10:43 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void org.mycompany.myservices.Cache.flush(java.lang.String), MUST return a non-void type.
Jan 23, 2012 10:10:43 AM com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory$InMemoryTestContainer stop
INFO: Stopping low level InMemory test container
```

My implementation of WS:

```
    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Building put(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String token, Building building) {
        try {
          BuildingsDelegator td = new BuildingsDelegator(verifyCredentials(token));
          return td.createBuilding(building);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
          building = new Building();
          building.setError("authentication did not succeed");
          return building;
        }

    }
```

And test case I run against:

```
public class BuildingTest extends JerseyTest {

    private String token ="DQAAAMMAAAB9ApLCubrBvuac0Y6lF8TH8FPXY5WzAhkwrqZv6tL0l9pu_xcY_9mVa1Q-sqTDlMXWUGoo8coYZGh8H2L2b_597O6StOyZ7N3uD-6v5HLNgPDWjj6YXl_X_LyEGM97z3JbSFire3J2Aw5Rag09BEweSMEjV-7TX3lqvtipWYJwQNWlSKpDl4F3TxBj-bWQulvFQ_wonLKze227Le3D_gB0JRofe3L5RkxBClkR6VKIx5s9fEbzupFz6t9hmKoNUTdRa14CgrQSaxXiPMO7J6G9";

    @Override
    protected AppDescriptor configure() {
    this.setTestContainerFactory(new InMemoryTestContainerFactory() );
    return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("org.mycompany.myservices")
    .contextPath("/").build(); }

    @Test
    public void put() {
        Building building = new Building();
        building.setBuildingId("test_id_1.0x");
        building.setTeamId("weakId");
        building.setBuildingStatus(2);
        building.setRunId((long) 1110705);

        Client client = Client.create(); 
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:9998/");
        RunBean resultBean = webResource
            .path("rest/building")
            .header("Authorization", token)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .post(RunBean.class,building);
        assertEquals(((Building)resultBean).getBuildingId(), building.getBuildingId());

    }
}
```

Comment: you can't use in memory test container factory and create connections to localhost:someport. The socket is not even opened in this case. Use client() call for getting your client or use other containers (grizzly2 for example)